# ONVIF: How to implement filter in EventBindingService::CreatePullPointSubscription

Tags: c++, gsoap, onvif

We're using gSoap 2.8.106 (since that's what Yocto Kirkstone provides). We've taken https://github.com/KoynovStas/onvif_srvd as a base and started implementing ONVIF S and T Profile. T Profile requires additional event filtering as can be seen in tests like EVENT-2-1-26-v17.06 BASIC NOTIFICATION INTERFACE – TOPIC SUB-TREE IN PULLMESSAGES FILTER. In `EventBindingService::CreatePullPointSubscription` you receive a `_tev__CreatePullPointSubscription` pointer. There's a member `Filter` which points to `wsnt__FilterType`:

```
/* complex XML schema type 'tev:CreatePullPointSubscription': */
class SOAP_CMAC _tev__CreatePullPointSubscription {
      public:
        /// Optional element 'tev:Filter' of XML schema type 'wsnt:FilterType'
        wsnt__FilterType *Filter;
```

But `wsnt__FilterType` doesn't have anything in it:

```
/* complex XML schema type 'wsnt:FilterType': */
class SOAP_CMAC wsnt__FilterType : public soap_dom_element {
      public:
        /// XML DOM element node graph
        std::vector<struct soap_dom_element> __any;
```

On [gSOAP - ONVIF examples: ONVIF_Extensibility](https://www.genivia.com/examples/onvif/index.html#ONVIF_Extensibility) it explains:

> ONVIF data types may be extensible, permitting additional elements and/or attributes. However, most scenarios associated with profiles do not require these extensions so we remove them by default to reduce the size of the generated source code.

> If specific element and/or attribute extensions to a complexType are still required in specific cases, then we simply use the typemap.dat file to add these as additional optional members to the generated classes/structs.

> Likewise, we add the following line to typemap.dat to add the wsnt:TopicExpression element to the tt:Filter element of tt:Events of the Events ONVIF WSDL:

```
tt__EventFilter = $ wsnt__TopicExpressionType *wsnt__TopicExpression;
```

If I do that then `tt__EventFilter` changes to:

```
class SOAP_CMAC tt__EventFilter : public wsnt__FilterType {
      public:
        /// XML DOM attribute list
        /// Typedef xsd__anyAttribute with custom serializer for struct soap_dom_attribute
        struct soap_dom_attribute __anyAttribute;
        /// Optional element 'wsnt:TopicExpression' of XML schema type 'wsnt:TopicExpressionType'
        wsnt__TopicExpressionType *wsnt__TopicExpression;
```

But that's not `wsnt__FilterType` which is what I'm getting from `_tev__CreatePullPointSubscription`. So what's the intention here?

I can change the line in `typemap.dat` to:

```
wsnt__FilterType = $ wsnt__TopicExpressionType *wsnt__TopicExpression;
```

then `wsnt__FilterType` becomes:

```
class SOAP_CMAC wsnt__FilterType : public soap_dom_element {
      public:
        /// XML DOM element node graph
        std::vector<struct soap_dom_element> __any;
        /// Optional element 'wsnt:TopicExpression' of XML schema type 'wsnt:TopicExpressionType'
        wsnt__TopicExpressionType *wsnt__TopicExpression;
```

Using `wsnt__TopicExpressionType` I can read `Dialect` but that's all there is. How can I read the rest of the filter details?

Once I read the filter, is there an implementation for it anywhere or do I have to write this from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the `wsdl/typemap.dat` file passed into `wsdl2h`:

```
wsnt__FilterType = $ std::vector<wsnt__TopicExpressionType*> TopicExpression            0;  ///< Multiple elements.
wsnt__FilterType = $ std::vector<wsnt__QueryExpressionType*> MessageContent             0;  ///< Multiple elements.
```

This will include serialization and deserialization code for the specified elements.

You should be able to get the Topic Expression from the `soap_dom_element` `__any`:

```
std::string topic = topicExpression->__any.get_text();
```